# How to handle a send parameter button in asp.net MVC c #?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

How to handle a send parameter button in asp.net MVC c #?

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
    <label>Nom : </label>
    <input type="text" id="NAME" name="NAME" class="form-control"  value=@Model.NAME required />
    <input type="submit" value="importer  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ajax begin Form to get it

**In the Html**

```
      @using (Ajax.BeginForm("test", "Inicio", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "Sucesso(data);" }))
      {
        <label>Nom : </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required />
        <input type="submit" value="importer" />
      }
```

**In The controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult test(string name)
    {
        return Json(new { retorno = name }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```